# ncmpcpp: playlist + library layout

Tags: arch-linux, tmux, mpd

I'm trying to replicate [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsnRA.png) ncmpcpp configuration

[image: ncmpcpp config]

found on [ArchLinux BBS](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1113439#p1113439).

It features a double-paned playlist window: on the left it shows a classic playlist, on the right there is a file browser (by default on window 3).

On the entire internet this is the first time I see such config, and I'm trying desperately to emulate it, without success. I've already tried tmux, but this seems far from a `splitw -h`, since the upper and lower parts of ncmpcpp are perfectly integrated with both panes.

Any hint?

Comment: Moreover, on ncmpcpp [site](http://ncmpcpp.rybczak.net/) in version 0.5.9 the function "merge views" is reported, but it is not documented anywhere.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It turns out that it is obtained by pressing `CTRL + L`, setting a splitting width and pressing the number of the screen to open (e.g. 5 for media library). As of 0.5.10 there is no way to set the split to persist a quit.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case somone still searching for a colution  - you can start like this:

```
ncmpcpp -s playlist -S visualizer
```

Saving this as an alias will do it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).